# Extract axis-angle from (scaled) identity matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I'm looking at an algorithm that extracts axis-angle from a rotation matrix.

The algorithm first checks if the matrix is symmetric and does some special calculations in that case (the normal algorithm is invalid on symmetric matrices). One thing it checks is if the matrix is the identity matrix in which case a random axis and zero angle is returned (the identity matrix has no rotation).

What I wonder is does it have to be exactly the identity matrix to have this property? Wouldn't a scaled identity matrix yield the same result? Isn't it in fact only the non-diagonal values in the matrix that has to be zero?

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$\text{identity matrix = no rotation}$$
\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0&0\\0&0.1&0\\0&0&3.2\end{bmatrix}
$$\text{scaled identity matrix = no rotation?}$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$\text{scaled (to zero) identity matrix = no rotation?}$$

One way to phrase this could be; if $R_{01}, R_{02}, R_{12}, R_{10}, R_{20}, R_{21}$ are all zero, is it ever possible to calculate axis-angle from the matrix?

Comment: Of course rotation and scaling are two different operations. A matrix can do them both at once. The amount of scaling is determined by the determinant of the matrix. For a pure rotation matrix, the determinant is exactly $1$. If you're multiplying by a zero matrix, you're scaling by a factor of zero. That doesn't make much sense, does it ...

Comment: I guess one could rephrase the question to "given any matrix created from scaling and/or rotation, what determines if it is even possible to get an axis-angle from it?" the identity matrix being one special case, but there should be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation matrix can be obtained with Rodrigues' rotation formula. If we denote the axis by $\vec{n} = n_x \vec{i} + n_y \vec{j} + n_z \vec{k}$ and the angle by $\Theta$, applying the rotation to any vector $\vec{v}$ gives the rotated vector
\begin{equation}\label{eq:euler-rodriguesPRA}
\vec{v}' = \left(\cos{\Theta} \right) \vec{v} + \left(1 - \cos{\Theta} \right) \left( \vec{v} \cdot \vec{n} \right)\vec{n} + \left( \sin{\Theta} \right) \left( \vec{n} \times \vec{v} \right)
\end{equation}
There are several ways of turning this into a usable matrix. [Murray](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf) presents the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R &= R_{\vec{n}}(\Theta) \\ &= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\Theta} + n_x^2\left(1- \cos{\Theta} \right) & n_x n_y \left(1-\cos{\Theta}\right) - n_z \sin{\Theta} & n_y \sin{\Theta} + n_x n_z \left(1-\cos{\Theta} \right)  \\
%
n_z \sin{\Theta} + n_x n_y \left(1-\cos{\Theta}\right) & \cos{\Theta} + n_y^2 \left( 1- \cos{\Theta} \right) & -n_x \sin{\Theta} + n_y n_z \left( 1- \cos{\Theta} \right) \\
%
-n_y \sin{\Theta} + n_x n_z \left( 1- \cos{\Theta} \right) & n_x \sin{\Theta} +  n_y n_z \left( 1-\cos{\Theta} \right) & \cos{\Theta} + n_z^2 \left( 1- \cos{\Theta} \right)
\end{array}
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The axis and the angle can be extracted from the rotation matrix $R$ by observation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:PRA-extraction}
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
 \cos{\Theta} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{trace}{\left(R\right)} -1 \right)  \\
 \vec{n} &= n_x \vec{i} + n_y \vec{j} + n_z \vec{k} \\
  &= 
\frac{R_{2,1} - R_{1,2} }{2\sin{\Theta}} \vec{i} +  \frac{R_{0,2} - R_{2,0}}{2\sin{\Theta}}  \vec{j} + \frac{R_{1,0} - R_{0,1}}{2\sin{\Theta}}  \vec{k}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
From this representation, you can formulate a condition when the axis and angle extraction is possible. Note that this assumes that the determinant of $R$ is $1$. If it isn't, one must divide the old matrix by its determinant.

Comment: `Note that this assumes that the determinant of R is 1. If it isn't, one must divide the old matrix by its determinant.` Now, this is the interesting part. What happens after we do this? Is it possible to get axis-angle from the new matrix with the above equation? Sometimes it must be a singularity that we can't get an axis from, right?

Comment: Well, you can look at the equation and determine the condition yourself. It's easy to see that $\sin{\Theta} \neq 0$ is an absolute requirement.

Comment: One can also see that if all the non-diagonal values in the matrix are `0` the length of the vector will also be `0` no matter the angle (which depends only on the diagonal). Hence answering my question that it is impossible to get an axis from such a matrix.

Comment: If you feel like I answered your question, feel free to upvote and mark my answer as accepted.